# AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'capitalize'

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use capitalize attribute from string module but I am fetting an error.

```
import string
s = "nishant sharma"
str = " ".join(map(string.capitalize, s.split(' ')))
print(str)
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3b3e3c5386cb> in <module>
  1 import string
  2 s = "nishant sharma"
----> 3 str = " ".join(map(string.capitalize, s.split(' ')))
  4 print(str)
```

AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'capitalize'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, avoid using built-ins and keywords such as `str` (which is a built-in class) as variable names. Second, `capitalize` is a method defined in the class `str`, not in the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module:

```
s = "nishant sharma"
s2 = " ".join(map(str.capitalize, s.split(' ')))
print(s2)
```

Output:

```
Nishant Sharma
```